# Adding sqlite framework to desktop Mac app

Tags: cocoa, xcode, sqlite

I'm using Xcode 3.1.3 to create a desktop Mac OS X 10.5.7 app.  I'd like to use sqlite in the app but can't find the framework reference in the MacOSX10.5.sdk folder.  I've used sqlite in iPhone apps and the reference comes from the iPhone sdk folders.  Should I just reference the iPhone sqlite framework version or is the desktop version hidden somewhere?

My goal is to access the iPhone apps' databases in the desktop Mac app.

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite is a builtin storage engine for [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). You're soaking in it :)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I finally found /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib, just like the iPhone.  So I don't need that?  Why does the iPhone need it (does it?)?

Comment: You don't need to use SQLite directly if you're using Core Data (which is also available on the iPhone since version 3.0). If you do use SQLite directly, then you'll have to use it in both places.

Comment: I have this at the top of my implementation file: 
#import <sqlite3.h>.  But keep getting sqlite errors during the linking stage.  For example: "_sqlite3_finalize", reference from...  It references the .o version of my file.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Did you drag libsqlite3.dylib into "Other Frameworks" in your Xcode ?